# JIRA / Greenhopper move subtasks when moving stories

Tags: task, jira, user-stories, greenhopper

If I have a bunch of subtasks in JIRA under a story, and I then mark the story (or Bug) as "resolved" (from In Progress), how can I make it mark all of the subtasks as resolved?

Likewise, if I have a bunch of subtasks and I move the last one from In Progress to Resolved, how can I make the story itself (or Bug) be marked Resolved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin with built in scripts that allows you to transition parent when all sub-tasks are resolved - https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/GRV/Built-In+Scripts#Built-InScripts-Transitionparentwhenallsubtasksareresolved
That answers second question.

First question is a bit more difficult to answer.

I cannot think of a plugin that does it, but you can always create your post-function plugin where you resolve all subtasks when parent gets resolved. You can try using of the scripting plugins - https://plugins.atlassian.com/search/with?q=scripting&product=all

There is an easy way of blocking an issue workflow by sub-task status which could be another way of working with sub-tasks - http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Sub-tasks#ConfiguringSub-tasks-BlockingIssueworkflowsbySubTaskstatus